# Waring's problem with bounded gaps

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Given an integer $k\geq 2$, Waring-type problems ask for the least number of $k$-th powers whose sums have some nice property.
According to the survey 'Waring's Problem: A Survey' by Vaughan and Wooley:

$g(k)$ is the least integer such that every natural integer $n$ is
a sum of $g(k)$ powers $n=\sum_{i=1}^{g(k)} a_i^k$ for suitable
integers  $a_1,\ldots,a_{g(k)}$ in $\mathbb N$.

$G(k)$ is the least integer such that every large enough natural integer $n$ is a sum ...

$G_1(k)$ is the least integer such that every integer $n$ in a set of density $1$ is a sum ...

**Has somebody some information on the following Waring-type problem:**

*What is the least integer $\gamma(k)$ such that the subset of $\mathbb N$ consisting of all elements of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{\gamma(k)}a_i^k$ (with $a_i$ in $\mathbb N$) has
only gaps of bounded size?*

There are two additional interesting objects: The size $s(k)$ of the largest gap occuring infinitely often and the finite set of
gaps of size strictly larger than $s(k)$.

The case $k=2$ is easy and we get $\gamma(2)=3$.
Indeed, given an integer $h$, chose $h$ distinct primes $p_1,\ldots,p_h$ which are all congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ and solve the congruences $x+i\equiv p_i\pmod{p_i^2}$ for $x$ in $\mathbb N$.
None of the $h$ consecutive integers $x+1,\ldots,x+h$ can be a sum of two squares.

On the other hand, every even integer is at distance $1$ from an integer in $1+4\mathbb N$ and every odd integer is at distance $1$ from an integer in $2+4\mathbb N$. All natural integers congruent to $1$ or $2$ modulo $4$ are sums of three squares. This shows that no gaps larger than $3$ can occur. (Gaps of size $3$ occur:
None of $111,112$ is a sum of three squares).

Notice that sums of three squares have density smaller than $1$.
Notice also that the set of all sums of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{\gamma(k)}a_i^k$ (for $a_i$ in $\mathbb N$)
has density at least $1/s(k)>0$ where $s(k)$ is the size of the largest gap occuring infinitely often.

Comment: "syndetic" might be a helpful search term

Comment: @mathworker21 . Thanks. Never heard this terminology.